# Boost 1.61 header is trying to redefine mpl_::bool_

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I'm on Boost 1.61 and compiling with clang 4.0.1 and I'm compiling for linux-gnu

Previously I was on Boost 1.52 and was not having this issue. Just by changing versions, I'm getting a compiler error about redefining `mpl_::bool_`

I'm not using any precompiled boost libs. This is headers only.

This is my include and the only include of boost:

```
#include <system/math/math.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
```

I'm getting a compiler error:

```
1>  In file included from myfile.cpp:9:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp:25:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/detail/managed_memory_impl.hpp:30:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/segment_manager.hpp:38:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp:30:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/allocators/detail/allocator_common.hpp:32:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp:35:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/interprocess/detail/posix_time_types_wrk.hpp:32:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:18:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:19:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_calendar.hpp:13:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:12:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:17:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp:12:
1>  In file included from boost_1_61_0\boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp:13:
1>  boost_1_61_0\boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp:41:21: error: target of using declaration conflicts with declaration already in scope
1>        using ::mpl_::bool_;
1>                      ^
1>  boost_1_61_0\boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp:32:29: note: target of using declaration
1>     template <bool B> struct bool_;
1>                              ^
1>  boost_1_61_0\boost/mpl/bool.hpp:23:28: note: conflicting declaration
1>  template< bool C_ > struct bool_
```

clang is using these args:
`-m64 -fdeclspec -Wall -mcx16 -msse4 -stdlib=libstdc++ -g -ggdb3 -O1 -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -Wextra -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB`

Comment: Thought maybe it was because clang is out of date, but even with 7.0 and still the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this which is a similar error: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/12212

Noticed that I had this defined for another lib, so I undef it for this include:

```
#undef BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_ADL_BARRIER_NAMESPACE
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_ADL_BARRIER_NAMESPACE
```